# how to optimize FirstOrDefault Statement in linq

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, linq

I have a two linq statements that the first one takes 25 ms and the second one takes 1100 ms second in a loop of 100,000.

I have replaced FirstAll with ElementAt and even used foreach to get the first element, but still takes the same time.
Is there any faster way to get the first element ?

I have considered few other questions but still couldn't find any solution to solve this problem.

```
var matches = (from subset in MyExtensions.SubSetsOf(List1)
                where subset.Sum() <= target
                select subset).OrderByDescending(i => i.Sum());
var match = matches.FirstOrDefault(0);
```

Also tried:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    break;
}
```

Or even:

```
var match = matches.ElementAt(0);
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

EDIT: here is the code for SubSetOf

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SubSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        // Deal with the case of an empty source (simply return an enumerable containing a single, empty enumerable)
        if (!source.Any())
            return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1);

        // Grab the first element off of the list
        var element = source.Take(1);

        // Recurse, to get all subsets of the source, ignoring the first item
        var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1));

        // Get all those subsets and add the element we removed to them
        var haves = haveNots.Select(set => element.Concat(set));

        // Finally combine the subsets that didn't include the first item, with those that did.
        return haves.Concat(haveNots);
    }

}
```

Comment: what does `MyExtensions.SubSetsOf(List1)` return? Share the code of method `SubSetsOf`, maybe an optimization in this method could improve the performance.

Comment: First statement does not do anything. It just precompiles the query. Second statement, in whatever form, does the actual query and thus takes so much longer to execute. That's how linq works, i don't think you can easily work this around

Comment: @Felipe: Thank you for your comment, I have attached it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jason said, it's a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) - the option of [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) where `weight` is equal to `value`. The simplest solution - generate all subsets and check thiers sum, but this algorithm has horrible complexity. So, our optimization does not matter.

You shoul use dynamic programmig to solve this problem:

Let assume a two-dimensional array `D(i, c)` - maximal sum of `i` elements that is less or equal to `c`. `N` - is amount of elements (list size). `W` - max sum (your target).
`D(0,c) = 0` for every `c`, because you have no elements :)
And changing `c` from `1` to `W` and `i` from `1` to `N` let's compute
`D(i,c) = max(D(i-1,c),D(i-1,c-list[i])+list[i])`.

To restore subset, we must store array of parents and set them during calculations.
Another examples are [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/).
Whole code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new[] { 11, 2, 4, 6 };
        var target = 13;

        var n = list.Length;
        var result = KnapSack(target, list, n);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.Write(item + " ");
        }
    }

    private static List<int> KnapSack(int target, int[] val, int n)
    {
        var d = new int[n + 1, target + 1];
        var p = new int[n + 1, target + 1];
        for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (var c = 0; c <= target; c++)
            {
                p[i, c] = -1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c <= target; c++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || c == 0)
                {
                    d[i, c] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    var a = d[i - 1, c];
                    if (val[i - 1] <= c)
                    {
                        var b = val[i - 1] + d[i - 1, c - val[i - 1]];
                        if (a > b)
                        {
                            d[i, c] = a;
                            p[i, c] = p[i - 1, c];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            d[i, c] = b;
                            p[i, c] = i - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d[i, c] = a;
                        p[i, c] = p[i - 1, c];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //sum
        //Console.WriteLine(d[n, target);

        //restore set
        var resultSet = new List<int>();
        var m = n;
        var s = d[n, target];
        var t = p[m, s];
        while (t != -1)
        {
            var item = val[t];
            resultSet.Add(item);
            m--;
            s -= item;
            t = p[m, s];
        }

        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate. its working perfectly, interestingly its the fastest solution and just takes 1 sec for 100,000 loop.

Comment: @albertsh yep, but my "wrong" answer has more voites :)

Comment: :) that one was so nice and technical, but this one is more optimized, I wish I could give more votes ;)

Comment: in case of using var list1 = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 9 }; and having target=4, the method's result is {2,2} which 2 is repeated instead of {1,2}. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @albertsh yes, there was a mistake in parents' restore path, i fixed it, try again

Answer (score 5):

You call Sum twice - it's bad. Precalc it:

```
        var matches = MyExtensions.SubSetsOf(List1)
                        .Select(subset => new { subset, Sum = subset.Sum() })
                        .Where(o => o.Sum < target).OrderByDescending(i => i.Sum);
        var match = matches.FirstOrDefault();
        var subset = match != null ? match.subset : null;
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same thing :)

Comment: Note that the object you get will be an anonymous class with field `subset` that contains the original object.

Comment: @Backs, you're missing `FirstOrDefault().subset`, no?

Comment: @d--b yes, it's the first most obvious optimization

Comment: @Backs, thank for your answer, unfortunately it still takes 1000 ms, please advice.

Comment: @albertsh I have one idea, but it's too late now, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: @albertsh SubSetsOf - is all subsets of list?

Comment: @Backs, Yes they are all List, Any way thank you for considering

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the general problem you are trying solve is to find the subset of numbers with the largest sum less than `target`.  The execution time of your linq function is a symptom of your solution.  That is a well known and much researched problem called the '[knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)'.  I believe your specific variant would fall into the 'bounded knapsack problem' class with the weight being equal to the value.  I would start by researching that.  The solution you have implemented, brute forcing every possible subset, is known as the 'naive' solution.  I am pretty sure it is the worst performing of all possible solutions.